# Apex: equivalent of send() or eval() string to variable or attribute

Tags: apex, map

If I have a map of strings like so:

```
public static Map<String, String> fieldTranslation() {
    Map<String, String> fieldTranslation = new Map<String, String>();
    fieldTranslation.put('Initial_System_Size__c',     'DEFAULT_INITIAL_SYSTEM_SIZE');
    fieldTranslation.put('System_Production__c',       'DEFAULT_SYSTEM_PRODUCTION');
    return fieldTranslation;
}
```

How can I write a function to find a key, and "send" each key and value to be evaluated as a variable or attribute?

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
public static Boolean isDefault(String field) {
    return (eval(fieldTranslation[field]) == (fieldTranslation[field].value()));
}
```

Any help'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: could you make your map be a set of key => constructed interface objects?  each interface would support a method called `eval()` and the  object's constructor would contain the necessary arguments needed to do the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly...

```
public static Boolean isDefault(SObject record, String field) {
    return record.get(field) == fieldTranslation.get(field);
}
```

Note that the methods we're talking about are `SObject.get` and `Map.get`; you can't do this with any generic object (i.e. we do not have true reflection), but those two methods should point you in the general direction.

Comment: That works for the `record.get()` part, but I have a variable in the class called `DEFAULT_SYSTEM_PRODUCTION` which I need to evaluate to get *its* value.

Comment: I imagine I want something like `Decimal.valueOf(fieldTranslation.get(field))`, but that returns an invalid decimal.

Comment: Also, just using the variable name in the map (i.e, not in a string) results in what I imagine is some sort of scoping error.

Comment: Oh. I see what you're getting at. Unfortunately, we don't have proper reflection, which limits your options. Most likely, you'd want something like a `Map<String, Object>`, which is as close as you can get to dynamic references.

Comment: Thanks so much. I've got a curveball now though: what if I have two rows with the same key? In effect, two default values? Like two rows like this (with different results: `fieldTranslation.put('System_Production__c',       'DEFAULT_SYSTEM_PRODUCTION')` and `fieldTranslation.put('System_Production__c',       'DEFAULT_SYSTEM_PRODUCTION2')`. How can I loop through _that_?

Comment: @CD-RUM Keys must be unique, so you couldn't have two possible values. Using the `Map<String, Object>` variable, you could have either a list or a single value, and then determine which one to use: `Object defaults = fieldTranslation.get('System_Production__c'); if(defaults instanceOf List<String>.class) { /* compare as list */ } else { /* compare as string */ }`. It might get a bit complicated though... Apex Code, being strongly typed, doesn't really support this sort of coding.

Comment: Yeah, I'm beginning to see that. Thanks for all your help.